# Sparse data becomes NaN when dropping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of some columns that are of a sparse datatype, for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.arrays.SparseArray([0, 0, 0]), "B": [55, 100, 55], "C": [4, 4, 4]})

    A   B   C
0   0   55  4
1   0   100 4
2   0   55  4
```

However, when I try to drop duplicates, the sparse series becomes NaNs.

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    A   B   C
0   NaN 55  4
1   NaN 100 4
```

My expected output is

```
    A   B   C
0   0   55  4
1   0   100 4
```

How can I prevent this from happening and keep the original values?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Added, sorry about that @BalajiAmbresh

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates` changes the `dtype` of the `A` column from `Sparse[int64]` to `Sparse[float64]` which uses `NaN` for missing entries instead of `0`. Why it does this I don't know however.

Answer (score 0):

`SparseArray` doesn't store `0` for integer datatype.
See the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.arrays.SparseArray.html?highlight=sparsearray#pandas.arrays.SparseArray) which says that by providing a `fill_value` as say, something like `np.inf`, all the elements other than `np.inf` would be stored. That said, if `np.inf` is not present in the dataset, it's basically invalidating the concept of sparse array.

Eg:

```py
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.arrays.SparseArray([0, 0, 0], fill_value=np.nan),
                "B": [55, 100, 55], "C": [4, 4, 4]})
print(df.drop_duplicates())
```

Output

```
   A    B  C
0  0   55  4
1  0  100  4
```